# How can I python twitter crawling (scraping) several keyword

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, keyword

I wrote the code.

But I don't think it's going to work.

I want to extract words from the concept of " or " rather than the concept of " and ".

It seems like only ' keyword 1 ' is extracted.

How do I make corrections?

```
import tweepy
import time
import os

search_term = 'keyword1'
search_term2= 'keyword2'

lat = "37.6"
lon = "127.0"
radius = "200km"
location = "%s,%s,%s" % (lat, lon, radius)


API_key = "11111"
API_secret = "22222"
Access_token = "33333"
Access_token_secret = "444"


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_key, API_secret)
auth.set_access_token(Access_token, Access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

c=tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
            q=(search_term or search_term2),
            rpp=1000,
            geocode=location,
            include_entities=True)

data = {}
i = 1
for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text
    print(i, ":", data)
    i += 1
time.sleep(1)


wfile = open(os.getcwd()+"/twtw2.txt", mode='w')   
data = {}   
i = 0       

for tweet in c.items():
    data['text'] = tweet.text   
    wfile.write(data['text']+'\n')  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)

wfile.close()
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. Also, you shouldn't include your secrets and tokens in code you post publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe  change this line

```
q=(search_term or search_term2),
```

to

```
q="{}+OR+{}".format(search_term,search_term2),
```

- Case matters here for the OR operator
- enter q as a string, not as an expression that is short-circuit evaluated

By the way, your credentials (from your post) also work for me.